# SwiftUI: Custom Modal Animation

Tags: animation, modal-dialog, swiftui

I made a custom modal using SwiftUI. It works fine, but the animation is wonky.

When played in slow motion, you can see that the `ModalContent`'s background disappears immediately after triggering `ModalOverlay`'s tap action. However, `ModalContent`'s `Text` views stay visible the entire time.

Can anyone tell me how I can prevent `ModalContent`'s background from prematurely disappearing?

Slow-mo video and code below:

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Button(
                    action: { withAnimation { self.isShowingModal = true } },
                    label: { Text("Show Modal") }
                )

                ZStack {
                    if self.isShowingModal {
                        ModalOverlay(tapAction: { withAnimation { self.isShowingModal = false } })
                        ModalContent().transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    }
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalOverlay: View {
    var color = Color.black.opacity(0.4)
    var tapAction: (() -> Void)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        color.onTapGesture { self.tapAction?() }
    }
}

struct ModalContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution** (thanks to @JWK):

It's probably a bug. It seems that, during the transition animation (when the views are disappearing) the `zIndex` of the two views involved (the `ModalContent` and the `ModalOverlay`) is not respected. The `ModalContent` (that is supposed to be in front of the `ModalOverlay`) is actually moved under the `ModalOverlay` at the beginning of the animation. To fix this we can manually set the `zIndex` to, for example, 1 on the `ModalContent` view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Button(
                    action: { withAnimation { self.isShowingModal = true } },
                    label: { Text("Show Modal") }
                )

                ZStack {
                    if self.isShowingModal {
                        ModalOverlay(tapAction: { withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 5)) { self.isShowingModal = false } })
                        ModalContent()
                            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                            .zIndex(1)
                    }
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The investigation that brings to a solution**

Transition animations in SwiftUI have still some issues. I think this is a bug. I'm quite sure because:

1) Have you tried to change the background color of your `ModalContent` from white to green?

```
struct ModalContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way it works (see the following GIF):

[image]

2) Another way to make the bug occur is to change the background color of your `ContentView` to, for example, green, leaving the `ModalContent` to white:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Button(
                    action: { withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 5)) { self.isShowingModal = true } },
                    label: { Text("Show Modal") }
                )

                ZStack {
                    if self.isShowingModal {
                        ModalOverlay(tapAction: { withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 5)) { self.isShowingModal = false } })
                        ModalContent().transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ModalOverlay: View {
    var color = Color.black.opacity(0.4)
    var tapAction: (() -> Void)? = nil

    var body: some View {
        color.onTapGesture { self.tapAction?() }
    }
}

struct ModalContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                    Text("Item 2")
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .padding(.top, 16)
                .padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even in this case it works as expected:

[image]

3) **But** if you change your `ModalContent` background color to green (so you have both the `ContentView` and the `ModalContent` green), the problem occurs again (I won't post another GIF but you can easily try it yourself).

4) Yet another example: if you change the appearance of you iPhone to Dark Appearance (the new feature of iOS 13) your `ContentView` will automatically become black and, since your `ModalView` is white, **the problem won't occur** and everything goes fine.

Comment: Appreciate the investigative work! I think you’re right that this is a bug. The behavior seems completely unexpected. It's also unclear why `ModalContent`'s background has opacity on the transition in some cases where only `.move(edge: .bottom)` is specified. I’ll file a report with Feedback Assistant.

Comment: Turns out there is actually a workaround here! It accounts for the perceived opacity change in my previous comment too. Just set `zIndex` on `ModalContent`: `ModalContent().transition(.move(edge: .bottom)).zIndex(1)`. For whatever reason, `ModalContent` is dropping behind `ModalOverlay` when the state changes. I still agree this is a bug, but this appears to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, now we get why the problem seemed to occur only when the ContentView and the child view had the same bg colour. Anyway yes, it's a bug. For now I'll modify my answer to explain what you found. If you want you can even answer your own question and then accept your answer.